# PySpark writing two dataframes to the same partition but separated by folder

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using Spark to write two different dataframes to the same partition, but I want them to be separated by folders at the end of the partition. i.e. first data frame will write to `yyyy/mm/dd/` and the second will write to `yyyy/mm/dd/rejected/`

Currently, I'm able to write first data frame to `yyyy/mm/dd/` and second data frame to `rejected/yyyy/mm/dd` using the following code:

```
  first_df.repartition('year', 'month', 'day').write \
    .partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day') \
    .mode("append") \
    .csv(f"{output_path}/")

  second_df.repartition('year', 'month', 'day').write \
    .partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day') \
    .mode("append") \
    .csv(f"{output_path}/rejected")
```

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **`rejected`** as literal value to **`second_df`** then include in **`partitionBy`** i.e.

```
second_df.withColumn("rej",lit("rejected")) \
    .repartition('year', 'month', 'day').write \
    .partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day','rej') \
    .mode("append") \
    .csv(f"{output_path}")
```

Other way would be using [**`hadoop file api`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957668/move-files-between-hdfs-directories-as-aprt-of-spark-scala-application) to move the files into the respected directory.

**`Update:`**

**`Rename the directory:`**

```
URI           = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path          = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem    = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    
fs = FileSystem.get(URI("hdfs://<name_node>:8020"), Configuration())
#rename the directory
fs.rename(Path(f'{output_path}/rej=rejected'),Path(f'{output_path}/rejected'))
```

Comment: This works and outputs the file in a folder `rej=rejected`. Would there be a way to have the folder named just `rejected`?

Comment: @AaronZhong, You can **rename** the directory, Please check the updated answer!